# regex - alphanumeric with space, but exclude only spaces without alphanumeric chars

Tags: regex

I am trying to get a match on a tags which have some text preceding it
few samples :

```
<p> some text here <a href="#">and here</a></p> <!--want match--><br/>
<p> some text here and number 55 <a href="#">and here</a>  </p> <!--want match--><br/>
<p>  <a href="#">and here</a></p> <!--do not want match--><br/>
```

Now when I use this regex

```
>[\w,.-_|]+<a (.*?)</a>\s*<
```

I do not get a match on any of these.
However, this regex

```
>[\s\w,.-_|]+<a (.*?)<\/a>\s*<
```

gives match on all 3, where I want only first 2 as match

The problem here is "\s" whitespace. 
I dont mind whitespace between text, but if there is only whitespace and no text, there should be no match.

How can I do that?

Comment: **Don't**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after but this will match the first 2 only:

```
>[^>]*\w[^>]*(<a [^<]*<\/a>)
```

This matches any anchor tag that is preceded by a space that is preceded by some literal text. Please clarify the question with some more examples if this isn't the intended result.

edit: removed redundant \s before group
edit: changed .* to [^>] to not skip tags

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it wont work if there is no space just before "<a". eg <p> some text<a...  will not work. I thought my requirement was clear from the question. In case it was not : in short, I want to match if there is any alphanumeric chars before "<a". If there is a space along with alphanumeric chars, I dont mind it can be a match (but space is optional). However, there should be no match if there is only space or new line or any non-alphanumeric chars before "<a"

Comment: Try that, I've removed the space and changed it to not skip over tags

e.g. `<p><p>abc</p>  <a href="#">and here</a></p> <!--do not want match--><br/>`